# How can I print string expressions one under the other in line in java?

Tags: java

In a school project, I need to print string expressions one under the other in the same alignment. How can I do that.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEr4E.png)

For example, in a situation like here, how can I print names, surnames and numbers in the same line, one under the other? Thank you in advance to everyone who answers and helps.

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Frankly, I haven't tried anything because I don't have enough knowledge, so I felt the need to write here.

Comment: People are here to help you, not to do your work. Try first, fail then ask a proper question showing what didn't work.

Comment: I don't want anyone else to do my job. I shared it to get ideas because I didn't know what to do. If you noticed, I didn't ask if you could do it, I asked how I could do it.

Comment: You can add spaces or tab characters to the strings to make the "columns" equal in width on each row.

Comment: Yes, I tried but the order changes in string expressions of different lengths. Thanks for your help but.

Comment: May I ask why you reversed my edit? It seems that it would have made your post more likely to be upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but I think you want to print a table of data out in Java. Try using the `System.out.format()` method. Here's a quick  example of how to use it:

```java
System.out.format("%-15s %-15s %-15s\n", "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3");
System.out.format("%-15s %-15s %-15s\n", "Hello", "World", "!");
System.out.format("%-15s %-15s %-15s\n", "This", "is", "a table");
```

This will output the following table to the console:

```
Column 1        Column 2        Column 3
Hello           World           !
This            is              a table
```

If you want to display the table in a more sophisticated way, (right now, it might not be very clear that it's a table at all!), you can try using a third-party library such as *j-text-utils* or *ASCIITable*. These libraries provide more advanced features such as sorting, row numbering, and more. Here's an example of how to use *j-text-utils* to print a table:

```java
TextTable tt = new TextTable(new String[]{"Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"}, new String[][]{
    {"Hello", "World", "!"},
    {"This", "is", "a table"}
});
tt.printTable();
```

This will output the following table to the console:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Column 1      | Column 2      | Column 3      |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| Hello         | World         | !             |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| This          | is            | a table       |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

If this isn't what you want to do, please update your question with more details. It's not very clear right now.